# New Website in Windows 10 IIS not loading

Tags: iis, windows-10

I am trying to learn IIS on my Windows 10 machine, and I watched a tutorial (for a previous version) on which they create a new Website, specify the directory, and they can open the site in the browser.

So I decided to try: At first, I tried to create a new folder in C:\inetpub, but it was giving me headaches with administrative permissions required just to create the directory! So I created a folder in my "D" drive, and put a single "index.html" there, but when I want to open the site, Chrome gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I tried modifying the security of the folder to include IIS_IUSERS, but the problem still exists.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Check IIS is properly installed and configured ,type 'localhost' in your browser, if everything is ok, you should be able to see the IIS welcome page.

Comment: Yeah, `localhost` works fine, but I am missing something in the process I followed to create my new Webstie, but I don't what that is